# Android annotation Rest Client code generation error

Tags: android, rest, android-studio, client, android-annotations

I'm using android annotation within **Android Studio** and I encounter an issue when implementing a **rest client**.
My code below.

Anyone can help on this?

i try to create a simple restClient

here is my **RestClient Code :+1**:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "https://www.azerty.com/soa/stock/service/stock",converters = { ProductMessageConverter.class, StringHttpMessageConverter.class })
public interface MyRestClient {
    @Get("/all")
    ProductList getAll();


    @Delete("/id/{id}")
    void deleteById(Integer id);
 }
```

When building the project I got this error :

> Error:(40, 25) error: reference to exchange is ambiguous
>   both method exchange(String,HttpMethod,HttpEntity,Class,Map) in RestTemplate and method exchange(String,HttpMethod,HttpEntity,ParameterizedTypeReference,Map) in RestTemplate match
>   where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
>   T#1 extends Object declared in method exchange(String,HttpMethod,HttpEntity,Class,Map)
>   T#2 extends Object declared in method exchange(String,HttpMethod,HttpEntity,ParameterizedTypeReference,Map)

And I see this class is generated by **Android-annotation** :

```
public final class MyRestClient_
    implements MyRestClient
{

    private String rootUrl;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public MyRestClient_(Context context) {
        rootUrl = "https://www.azerty.com/soa/stock/service/stock";
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ProductMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public ProductList getAll() {`enter code here`
        return restTemplate.exchange(rootUrl.concat("/all"), HttpMethod.GET, null, ProductList.class).getBody();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Integer id) {
        {
            HashMap<String, Object> urlVariables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            urlVariables.put("id", id);
/*ERROR IS BECAUSE OF THE NEXT LINE*/            
restTemplate.exchange(rootUrl.concat("/id/{id}"), HttpMethod.DELETE, null, null, urlVariables);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This issue is solved.
For info I used the v3.2 of android annotations and I have to use 3.3.1.

Thanks to official android annotations team for their quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

I also posting the answer here for convenience.

The problem here is Spring for Android 2.0 introduced a new overload of the `exchange` method, for the [new generics support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-android/docs/2.0.0.M1/api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html). This made the calls generated by AA ambigous. The problem is solved from AndroidAnnotations version 3.3. But you should upgrade to 3.3.1, which is the current latest version. See [this](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/pull/1166) for more info.